# Remote command line execution using cpp program

Tags: c++

I want to execute the commands on remote machine (linux box) and catch the return code of commands in cpp code. Could you please help me in finding out the better approach? i found one library libssh but not sure about the performance. Thanks

Comment: You could use MPI: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/

Comment: `i found one library libssh but not sure about the performance` Might I suggest you try it, and if the performance is not good enough, then you look for something different?